# Pythonic way of retrieving values with a matrix of indices?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an h-by-w-by-3 numpy array `A` and another h-by-w-by-2 numpy array `B` that tells me where to grab the value from in `A` at each (h, w) location. Denote the result matrix by `C` (h-by-w-by-3).

Naively, I can do

```
C = np.zeros(A.shape)
for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[1]):
        C[i, j, :] = A[B[i, j, 0], B[i, j, 1], :]
```

But I'm sure there's more efficient, more pythonic, and faster way!

Comment: `C = A[B[:, :, 0], B[:, :, 1]]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> h, w = 4, 6
>>> 
>>> A = np.random.randint(0, 100, (h, w, 3))
>>> B = np.random.randint(0, h*w, (h, w, 2)) % [h, w]
>>> 
>>> C = np.zeros(A.shape)
>>> for i in range(B.shape[0]):
...     for j in range(B.shape[1]):
...         C[i, j, :] = A[B[i, j, 0], B[i, j, 1], :]
... 
>>> 
>>> C2 = A[(*np.moveaxis(B, 2, 0),)]
>>> np.all(C == C2)
True
```

Comment: Amazing. Seems that `*` is doing the magic here. Wonder how one actually tries the `*` operator? It's hard as it is usually inside the argument field...

Comment: @SibbsGambling In this particular case `(*np.moveaxis(B, 2, 0),)` is actually just a fancy way of writing `tuple(np.moveaxis(B, 2, 0))`. See for example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448).